# Pass URL with Notifying

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am wondering if it possible to configure the remote notify option to pass a URL.

I see there is a function for `onErrorRemoteDisableDenial`. I tried to modify it, but it seems to disables the app. Even if i put code to continue, the next call to the backend does not work.

But what we are looking for is giving the user the option to update via URL, or just continue with the app version they currently have.

Using Worklight 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to customize both Remote Disable and Remote Notify, but the `downloadLink` (the link that you've set in Worklight Console) is available only when setting Remote Disable, not Remote Notify. Only the `message` (the text set in Worklight Console) will be available.

You can customize the Remote Notify flow by using the following in main.js (outside of any function):

```
wl_remoteDisableChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(message,downloadLink) {
    WL.SimpleDialog.show(
        "New Version",
        message, 
        [
         {text: "Download", handler: function() {
             // Maybe use WL.App.openURL(downloadLink) to go to the app store
         }},
         {text: "Close", handler: function() {
             // Continue with the app
         }}
        ]);
};
```

`wl_remoteDisableChallengeHandler.handleChallenge` overrides the default Remote *Notify* code path. `wl_remoteDisableChallengeHandler.handleFailure` will override the default Remote *Disable* code path (and [this is another way](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_create_a_customized_remote_disable_behavior?lang=en) to customize Remote *Disable*).

Edit: per the findings in the comments, in order to get both the `message` and `downloadLink`, you will first need to temporary set Remote Disable and then change to Remote Notify, this is a workaround because Remote Notify by default is not meant to also pass the downloadLink to the default provided dialog.

Note: Remote Notify is meant to be displayed only once per a message's life cycle, so after it was displayed - it will not be displayed again until a the message is set again in the console.

A way to get the code to work on each application launch is to clear the application's HTML local storage (at some point while the app is running), where a "flag" is stored to tell the application not to display the message again (I forgot its name, but you could print the contents of the local storage and debug that).

Sounds like a nice feature request: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help

Comment: Thanks, idan.   I tried to override the disable challenger, but that seems to be a no go, because if you override the handler and try to continue, you cant because all calls to adapters give you::{"WL-Authentication-Failure":{"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"message":"Disabled","downloadLink":"http:\/\/www.google.com","messageType":"BLOCK"}}}*/ .  Will try to request as a feature..

Comment: That will happen if you use handleFailure; did you try handleFailure or handleChallenge? but I don't think it matters either way for the same reasons I have outlined in my answer.

Comment: Actually, i think your handle challange will work, even though the console does not show URL box, it does pass what was the previous value::{"message":"Notifying","downloadLink":"http://www.google.com","messageId":"1439308189531","messageType":"NOTIFY"}...  so i can temporary set it to disable to set the URL, then set it to notify

Comment: Ah, interesting. You might want to inform the administrator to set that disable rule at night then. :) and also keep in mind that this notify dialog displays only once (unless you delete its specific property from the HTML5 local storage); as always, if this helped - please mark as Answered... I will update the answer accordingly based on your findings.

Comment: Seems that the handleChallenge function is the one that sets and checks the messageId into local storage, so just overriding it overrides that feature. Thanks